# SQL Server: sharding a table..if that makes any sense

Tags: database, sql-server-2005

Just recently I noticed the total rows in one of my tables to be a staggering 1.2 million (it might not be amusing to some of you... but yes this is my first time having see such large number of rows)

So coming back to my point, the table is called `UserMaster` and now using SQL Server Management Studio, when I do a simple

```
select * from Usermaster
```

it takes 25 minutes to fetch all the rows!

I know I could resort to indexes to speed up my query, but out of curiosity, is  there any other way to sort this issue.... I did my googling before posting this is here and I came across the term *Database Sharding* which sounded quite relevant to my problem.

I mean, the way we could divide the original database into more than one, based on say, country and then changing the application code to identify which database to hit based on the country of the user so that the load gets divided and the query will in turn run faster..

Can someone suggest remedies on the same line, for my problem (if possible) ??

Comment: Seems to me putting in one or two proper indices would be **a lot** easier than setting up sharding ... sharding has its place when you're dealing with **hundreds of millions** of rows... but 1.2 million is by no means staggering.....

Comment: Is in on purpose you don't have a where? Your query returns all 1.2 million rows so adding an index would not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Database sharding is a hugely laborious task. Just create the proper indexes. That is easy and exactly what they are made for.

Sharding is for distributing data and load across servers. If you don't need that, add an index.